# Python carriage return not working

Tags: python, stdout

I have a long-running script that loops over rows in a database. Every so often I'd like it to print how many rows it's processed, but without creating a new line each time. This is essentially what I have:

```
import sys
mystr = "{} rows complete\r"

for i in range(0, 100):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        sys.stdout.write(mystr.format(i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

When I run this (on Python 2.7.5 64-bit, Windows) I get:

```
0 rows complete
10 rows complete
20 rows complete
...
100 rows complete
```

Can anyone think of why the carriage return isn't working? I've seen some similar questions here about Python and `\r`, but all the answers say to include `sys.stdout.flush()`, which I have.

Comment: Is this executing on windows?

Comment: Yes it's on Windows.

Comment: Works for me on Python 2.7.7 and 3.3 (though a call to `time.sleep()` helps to see the earlier lines. The difference could be that I'm running the 32-bit version, or the 0.0.2 version difference, or could be how you are running it: how are you running the script? I tried both from powershell and from cmd.exe and it works either way for me.

Comment: It does however go wrong if run from Powershell ISE. Are you using Powershell ISE to run your script?

Comment: Ahhh you know what -- I was running it from the console of my text editor (Sublime Text). When I ran it through cmd.exe it worked fine! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\r` is probably the correct way to go here, but the behaviour depends very much on how the text is being output. Not all terminals will respect a bare carriage return:

`cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` should both output the text the way you expect (Powershell ISE doesn't but that's a red herring here).

Python's own `idle` will ignore the carriage return, all output comes on one long line.

As you noted, your own editor's command window also ignores `\r`.

Also, if you try from an interactive window you also get some numbers output at the end of each line: that's because the interactive windows helpfully outputs the result of the call to `sys.stdout.flush()`.