# Python shell does not print carriage returns

Tags: python, console, python-idle, carriage-return

I'm using IDLE (Python 2.7) on Debian Wheezy. I sourced questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575014/python-carriage-return-not-working). I tried applying what they said, and I got some strange results. If I print carriage returns or backspaces in the Python shell, rather than actually *getting* those, I get squares with `bs` and `cr` in them. I can't show them here because they don't copy over.

How can I get an actual carriage return?
This is my code, based on the questions I cited above:

```
sys.stdout.write("Extracted: %d% Skipped %d% \r" % (len(f),len(skipped)))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: It sounds like you did get one, but your terminal didn't do what you wanted.  This is a terminal behavior issue.

Comment: @FatalError the terminal in this case is IDLE, which is common enough to make this an answerable question. That said, I can't reproduce it on Windows with either Python 2.7 or 3.5. The OS and Python version should be added to the question.

Comment: Corrected it @MarkRansom.

Comment: IDLE on Ubuntu here also does not produce the usual carriage return behavior.  I expect that if you run your code in a more general linux terminal you will see the behavior your are expecting.

Comment: Except for `\n`, IDLE prints output in response to input as received.  1. IDLE is a development environment, not a runtime environment.  Developers mostly need to see literal output.  To see runtime behavior, test in intended runtime environment.  2. Shell is a text window, not a terminal. 3. The text window is based on tk Text, so that determines default behavior.  4. There is no standard terminal.  The unix termcap system is evidence.  5. Should backspace/return delete as well as move? 6. For complete control of output use tkinter.  7. There should be terminal widgets available on PyPI.

Comment: In spite of what I said above, I have considered adding simple backspace/return interpretation to IDLE *as an option*.   But see 5. above.  There is also an issue with how to turn on the option from within a program, or at least the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminals vary in their capabilites of handling such special characters. A similar question [was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19188881/2465194) by [Wayne Werner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344286/wayne-werner), who said that IDLE just does not handle those special characters (i.e. printing a stand-in character, rather than moving the cursor or deleting.), which may be for good reason.

Short of writing a patch as Wayne mentioned, you may find that running your program in the native terminal does work as expected. (i.e. `python path/to/your/program`).

## From Comments

If you would like the program to be aware of it's environment (as was asked in the comments) it is possible (and perhaps most simple) to create a command line switch that is set manually at the program's execution. If you launch from a shortcut or another program (perhaps a batch file) you could automate the process by incorporating it into the pre-written command.

Such a switch could look like:

```
python path/to/your/program --terminal //For a full terminal
python path/to/your/program --IDLE //For IDLE
```

#### Note

After reading [Terry Jan Reedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722804/terry-jan-reedy)'s comment, I'd to point out that his guidance toward tkinter(and on the general facets of this situation) may in fact be the most helpful for a thorough solution to the issue. Check [those comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38104602/2465194) out.

Comment: How can I tell which one I'm in, though? If that's the case, I only really want to show this behavior in terminals that are capable of displaying it.

Comment: @ares Interesting idea, my quick search didn't find much of anything promising. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9839240/2465194) has a number of somewhat hackish solutions that you may want to try.

Comment: @ares, perhaps the most straightforward approach is introducing a command line switch that you set manually. If you launch from a shortcut or another program you could hide this switch by incorporating into the command.