# Carriage return not moving to beginning of the line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pycharm, escaping

I am using **carriage return** in between a string.
However, it is not working as expected.

```
string = 'My website is Latracal \rSolution'
print(string)
```

Expected Output:

```
Solutionte is Latracal
```

Actual Output:

```
My website is Latracal Solution
```

My python version is **python 3.10**
I am using `IDLE` as the terminal emulator.

When running the same code in `PyCharm` I get the following output:

```
Solution
```

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? Does it support overwriting lines?

Comment: Related: [How to overwrite the previous print to stdout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5419389/11082165)

Comment: Are you using IDLE? If so, this may be a duplicate of [Carriage Return not working in IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35768165/11082165). Otherwise it may be a duplicate of the more general [Python carriage return not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26575014/11082165)

Comment: can you please check my updated question?